# Custom content type in Microsoft Sharepoint Services

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have to create a library with links to existing files. The files is on the FileChange server. I don't know how to create a custom content type, without the file field. Is it possible at all?

P.S. Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to create your custom content type?
If so, please take a look at this article: [Creating and using Custom Site Content Types in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006-7-Creating_and_using_Custom_Site_Content_Types_in_Microsoft_Office_Sharepoint_Server_2007.aspx)

Hope this helps.